# Why aren't the addition field columns populating when I select a value from a lookup column?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, lookup-column, column

I have an `Equipment List` that looks like this:

```
Number   Description   Mill Area
1        pump          warehouse
2        motor         outside
3        shaft         yard
4        bearing       office
```

I want to create a list for an inventory form. I have a `Lookup (information already on this site)` type column that points to the `Equipment List`. So when you go to create a new form, it presents a dropdown of all the equipment numbers in that list.

However, I want it to also grab the description column. Now, the feature "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" seems like it should work.

[image]

[image]

However, when I complete the form and select a number. The corresponding Equipment Description and Mill Area columns aren't imported, they just remain blank.

[image]

Anyone know why it isn't working the way I thought it would, or what alternatives are there? Instead of using the Equipment Number I've tried using the ID, and that didn't help. I also tried enforcing Enforce Unique Values in the equipment number column to see if that helped, also no change.

Comment: What type of column is it that you're looking up to?

Comment: It's a string column